# Print Mysql Insert query in magento

Tags: magento

I just want to print and check the insert query in magento. I have searched in google and tried alot but not able to print the insert query in magento.

My code:

```
  $insert = Mage::getModel('instagram/instagram');
        $insert->setData('username',$data->user->username);
        $insert->setData('name',$data->user->full_name);
        $insert->setData('Bio',$data->user->bio);
        $insert->setData('Website',$data->user->website);
        $insert->setData('user_id',$data->user->id);
        $insert->setData('instagram_access_token',$data->access_token);
        $insert->save();
```

Can anyone tell me to do???

Comment: Do you have a Magento collection code for this?

Comment: I have updated, pls check it.

Comment: Should be migrated to http://magento.stackexchange.com (?)

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql** under
**lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php** and change global variables :

```
protected $_debug               = false;
protected $_logAllQueries       = false;
```

to

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
```

then run your script and you should see  the query under 
**var/debug/pdo_mysql.log**  or whatever file specified in

```
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
```

Don't forget to restore all modified values when you finish logging the query, if the file do not exists after running the script, make sure that magento has permissions under that directory

Comment: I had done the steps that you have mentioned, but i did not get the query in log file.

Comment: Do you have enable logging?, check in admin panel  System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings, also make sure that folder var/log has 777 permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$insert = Mage::getModel('instagram/instagram');
echo $insert->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: I think this will print only select query, I asked for printing insert query.